# Can't import ObtainAuthToken

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, token

I am new to Django.

In the course that i'm using he is importing `ObtainAuthToken` like this:

`from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken`

But when i try to do the same thing i get this exception:

`Abstract base class containing model fields not permitted for proxy model 'TokenProxy'.`

What am i doing wrong?

I have added both my app and 'rest_framework' to my Installed_Apps.

If this needs clarification i can send my views and urls files also.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Django REST Framework 3.12.x. https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/7561

For the time being, downgrade to 3.11.x (`pip install -U 'djangorestframework<3.12'`).

Comment: First time faceing these kind if issues.
Thanks a lot you saved my day.